# Installing python-setuptools 20.4 or greater on CENTOS 7 for CKAN server

Tags: centos, virtualenv, setuptools, ckan

I am trying to install setuptools 20.4 or greater as it is a requirement for CKAN. I have tried downloading the rpm files and installing it but CKAN does not recognize the python2 rpm. 
I am running a virtualenv for the ckan server under use ckan with the bash shell.
Does anybody have advice on how to properly install setuptools 20.4 or greater on centos?

Comment: It's not a hard requirement for ckan - it is specified to catch some edge cases. You will probably have no issue with using an older setuptools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update python to version 2.7.13 and then download setuptools from the python repository. Centos doesn't have official support for any python above 2.7.5 which is problematic as I have to add exclusions to yum update. Ckan does require setuptools installed this is not optional, on install it is listed as a critical error.

Comment: This is helpful but still seems to conflict with other experiences. Can you provide the commands you used and the error messages they gave?

Comment: It was a while ago so I don't remember and I no longer have access to documents. I know that when using redhat you need to install setuptools to get the latest version of python installed on the virtualenv. You log into the virtualenv and use setuptools to upgrade itself, then upgrade python

Answer (score 0):

If not using pip to upgrade setuptools, install/upgrade setuptools *before* you create the virtualenv.

I believe the rpm will update the system python's setuptools. When you create the virtualenv it copies the system setuptools into the virtualenv.

Comment: First try: using yum install python-setuptools
Second: installed using rpm from centos website
Third: Attempted to install from python wheel using pip

The setuptools package is being installed and the package I downloaded is the latest version or exactly 20.4 but centos always just sees it as 0.9.8 which makes ckan installation fail. I ended up installing an older version of ckan and it worked, seems that 2.7.0 is not compatible with centos 7 at this point

Comment: "[CKAN] 2.7.0 is not compatible with centos 7 at this point" - is not correct. As I said, it should work with any setuptools version - just skip that step during install.

Comment: "centos always just sees [setuptools] as 0.9.8" Provide the commands you used to determine that and maybe a Centos person can help you. This doesn't sound related to ckan.